# What do I return from Java Html 5 web application to play sound file with audiocontrol tag

Tags: java, html, html5-audio

I want to be able to play audio files from my Java based web application

Now its possible if the file physically sits in a folder below the root folder of my web application

```
  <audio controls="controls">
            <source src="/musicserver/test.mp3">
        </audio>
```

but not if it is somewhere else on the machine, I got round this using a symbolic link but this caused another issue that means I cannot use this approach.

So another solution suggested was to instead call a playmusic endpoint passing it the file path as a parameter. like this.

```
  <audio controls="controls">
            <source src="/musicserver/playmusic?url=/musicfolder/test.mp3">
        </audio>
```

But I dont know what this endpoint should actually do. The server is written in Java and I can read the file okay, **but what should it actually return to allow audio controls to play the music**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the response mime type to `audio/mpeg`, read the mp3 file as raw bytes, basically any servlet response beside `xml/json/html` you want to write `byte[]` to response stream.

```
res.setContentType("audio/mpeg");

//this whole block should be in a try catch 
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("yourmp3file.mp3"));
int c;
while((c=fis.read())!=-1){
    res.getWriter().write(c);

}
res.getWriter().flush();
```

Comment: okay looks easy enough, but not neccessarily mp3s, for example I note with Firefox it can play wav files so what would I set contentType to in that case, or do I not need to actually set it

Comment: you can get the list of mime type [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)

Comment: Thanks it worked, but unfortunately there are related problems, if you have any idea on these it would be appreciated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693730/why-does-html5-audio-load-all-songs-from-server-on-file-load