# When using html5 why does Firefox set length of wav tracks served by server as 6:45:48 duration

Tags: html, firefox, bootstrap-4, html5-audio

When using html5 why does *Firefox* set length of wav tracks servby server as 6:45:48 duration , i.e over six hours.

This occurs when i use `preload = none` and am serving the audio as a steam of bytes from the server

```
<audio controls="controls" preload="none">
            <source src="/fixsongs.play_music?url=E:\TestMusic\TestMusic\WAV\Music\Choir of Trinity College\Carols From Trinity\01 - Wachet Auf.wav">
        </audio>
```

If Firefox accesses the file directly as a local file

```
<audio preload="none" controls="controls">
            <source src="file:/E:/TestMusic/TestMusic/WAV/Music/Choir%20of%20Trinity%20College/Carols%20From%20Trinity/01%20-%20Wachet%20Auf.wav">
    </audio>
```

it displays the correct length.

Note in both cases it does actually play the file okay, but why can't it display correct length or at least choose a better default.

I tried with *Windows Edge* and that worked okay, it takes a little while to start playing but displays correct duration.

I tried with *Google Chrome*, this also works by sidestepping the issue and not displaying the length

I tried with Mp3s instead of Wavs and this was okay on *Firefox*.

Is there a way to fix this, alternatively is there a way to hide the duration bit (like Chrome does once it starts playing)

**Edit**

As suggested by Albert I have set order of preload and controls and have mimetype of audio, but it made no difference.

```
 <audio preload="none" controls="controls">
            <source type="audio/wav" src="/fixsongs.play_music?url=E:\TestMusic\TestMusic\WAV\Music\David Ferrard\Across The Troubled Wave\13 - Hard Times Come Again No More.WAV">
        </audio>
```

But I am not clear if I have do something on the server, I dont see how I can set the mimetype of the response since I am just returning the contents of the files as a series of bytes.

Here is an example:

When the page first loads time is shown 0:00 (because I have preload set to none), but as you click on each file to play the time changes to 6:45:48, all songs play correctly but the displayed total time is wrong.

[image]

Comment: look at your examples. the attributes are in different places, and the URLs are slightly different. try using the same markup first. also probably a good idea to indicate the type attribute on the source element.

Comment: I cant see how that would cause it to be ok on Chrome/Edge but not Firefox

Comment: because they are different codebases and do things differently. source element order matters if you are trying to get cross browser coverage. attribute order matters on meta elements. there are two examples. webkit browsers don't read file type, they read the extension. type attributes matter too.

Comment: looking at your post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693730/why-does-html5-audio-load-all-songs-from-server-on-file-load i'm willing to bet the types aren't being set on your server. have you set/confirmed which mime types these files are being served as?

Comment: albert you are correct they are not set, I will try and work out how do that.

Comment: hope this helps https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types

Comment: @albert i have updated my question

Comment: Im also now setting reponse to "audio/wav" but makes no difference. Is there any way to hide just the time part of ther controls ?

Comment: yes, though if you could show a picture of exactly what you mean....better yet a gist with this code and wav, i could be of more assistance

Comment: its not a problem specific to a particular wav

Comment: not sure why you thought that; without being able to see what is happening, can't help

Comment: because it happens for all wavs, okay can you get  wav file to diaply correct time when served by server on Fitrefox ?

Comment: i wouldn't serve wav files to firefox. i wouldn't serve wav files in general, not enough cross browser support. i'm trying to help; if you don't want to show your example that is fine, but i've done all i can here.

Comment: Albert I have no problem showing you but Im not sure exactly what  you want to see. In fact the product is released http://www.jthink.net/songkong/en/download.jsp so if you want I can give detailed instructions on how to see error. Im serving wavs when the user is adding metadata for wavs, if they are editing mp3s I will show mp3s and so on.

Comment: trying to see exactly what you are seeing so i can help...that page is a bunch of downloads.

Comment: I have added screenshot to question. Yes that page is a load of downloads my suggestion was you could download and install the (free) program, and then run the task on some wav files and see if you get the same issue as I do, but I realize that is quite alot to ask of you.

Comment: well i downloaded it, but don't understand what i have to do. don't use itunes/don't have any wav files. from your pix looks like shadow dom. webkit styles for that are easy to find. firefox....not so much. but i'll dig around.

Comment: try here: https://github.com/iandevlin/iandevlin.github.io/blob/master/mdn/video-player-styled/css/styles.css

Comment: Okay, thanks I will look at those styles  to try and remove the offending total length as doesnt seem possible to fix the length.

Comment: Having same problem with localStorage (no server). Any new developments? For my `.wav` files clicking page refresh toggles back and forth between 1 or 2 seconds and 6:45:48 for two files. On a third file it toggles between 1 second and 13:31:36. It's 100% reproducible with straight page refreshing and no buttons clicked in-between.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From quick searching on bugzilla, I found that this is a **know bug** reported [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1416976). The bug report has [this](https://bug1416976.bmoattachments.org/attachment.cgi?id=8928068) attachment, if you open up it in the firefox you will see player on your right displays exactly same duration that you posted in your question. However, after you play the file, the issue goes away when you reload the page, unless you clear history, in that case problem will occur next time you load the page again.

To solve this issue, make sure you are sending content-length header from the server when serving wav files.

Comment: Thankyou for finding that, and providing a way I can fix my code I will look into it.

Comment: Note that sending `Content-Length` headers for chunked files violates the HTTP/1.1 standard. [See discussion here](https://github.com/tomaka/rouille/issues/249#issuecomment-1005690444).

Comment: Any new developments? For my `.wav` files clicking page refresh toggles back and forth between 1 or 2 seconds and 6:45:48 for two files. On a third file it toggles between 1 second and 13:31:36. It's 100% reproducible with straight page refreshing and no buttons clicked in-between.